# tinymce - Cannot call method 'getContent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Nor-Avetisyan Admin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL ?>views/admin/css/navi.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL ?>views/admin/css/style.css">
    <script src="<?php echo URL ?>views/js/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL ?>views/admin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea"
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.n_warning,.n_ok,.n_error').hide();
            $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).attr('id'),
                    url = document.URL;
                $('.n_warning').fadeOut(500);
                $('.n_warning').fadeIn(500);
                $('.n_warning').html('<p>Are you sure? <button class=\"yes\">YES</button><button class=\"no\">NO</button></p>');

                    $('.yes').click(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '/admin/delete',
                                data: {
                                    id:id
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#'+id).fadeOut(500);
                    $('#adm-notification').html(data);
                        }
            });
                        setInterval(window.location = url,1000);
                     });
                    $('.no').click(function(){
                        $('.n_warning').fadeOut(500);
                    });
            });
            $('.button-save').click(function(b){
                b.preventDefault();
                var title = $('#title').val(),
                    category = $('#category').val(),
                    file = $('#file').val(),
                    short_content = tinyMCE.get('short_content').getContent(),
                    content = tinyMCE.get('content').getContent(),
                    date = $('#date').val(),
                    language = $('#language').val();
                alert(short_content);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/admin/save',
                    data: {
                        title:title,
                        category:category,
                        file:file,
                        short_content:short_content,
                        content:content,
                        date:date,
                        language:language
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.adm-notification').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$lang = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lang']);
$query_edit = mysql_query("SELECT id, category, title, img, short_content, content, date, lang FROM `news` WHERE id='$id' AND lang='$lang'");
//echo $id;
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="top">
                <div class="left">
                    <p>Welcome, <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?></strong> [ <a href="/admin/logout">logout</a> ]</p>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <div class="align-right">
                        <p>Avetisyan | Admin Panel</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="nav">
                <?php include '/views/admin/upper-menu.php'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="h_title">&#8250; Pages</div>
                    <?php include '/views/admin/left-menu.php'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <div class="full_w">
                    <div class="adm-notification"></div>
                    <div class="n_error"><p></p></div>
                        <?php
                        while($edit = mysql_fetch_array($query_edit)){
                            print "
                            <h2>".$edit['lang']." - ".$edit['title']."</h2>
                    <div class=\"entry\">
                        <div class=\"sep\"></div>
                    </div>

                            <form action=\"\" method=\"post\">
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"name\">Page title <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <input id=\"title\" name=\"name\" value=".$edit['title']." class=\"text\" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"category\">Category <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <input id=\"category\" name=\"category\" value=".$edit['category']." class=\"text\" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"attach\">Attachments</label>
                        <input type=\"file\" id=\"file\" name=\"attach\" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"short-content\">Short content <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <textarea name=\"short_content\" id=\"short_content\" class=\"textarea\" rows=\"10\">".$edit['short_content']."</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"content\">Long content <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <textarea name=\"content\" id=\"long_content\" class=\"textarea\" rows=\"10\">".$edit['content']."</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"date\">Date <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <input id=\"date\" name=\"date\" class=\"text\" value=".$edit['date']." />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"language\">Language <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <input id=\"language\" name=\"language\" value=".$edit['lang']." class=\"text\" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"entry\">
                        <button type=\"submit\" id=\"button-save\" class=\"add button-save\">Save page</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                            ";
                        }
                        ?>

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <div class="left">
                <p><a href="http://webex.am">Webex Technologies LLC</a> | Admin Panel: <a href="/">Avetisyan</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code.. I'm trying to get value of textareas (there are two of them). But its showing error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContent' of undefined

TinyMCE version is TinyMCE 4.0

Please give me solution, i need to solve this today as well. Thanks!!

Comment: Does it still give you an error if you move it into `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: tinyMCE.get('content').getContent(), should be tinymce.get('content').getContent(),

Comment: Does that solve your problem? In the TinyMCE code I can find `window.tinymce=window.tinyMCE`, so this shouldn't matter, does it?

Comment: $(document).ready() doenst work.